# O que significam esses colchetes duplos misteriosos em javascript?

Tags: javascript, promises

Digamos que eu crie uma Promise ***a*** em javascript:

```
var a = new Promise(function(success, error){  { sucess("Sucesso!"); })
```

Minha variável a recebe as seguintes propriedades:

```
Promise {[[PromiseStatus]]: "resolved", [[PromiseValue]]: "Sucesso!"}
```

Porém, reparem que elas estão com colchetes duplos envolvendo-as. Gostaria de saber como faço para pegar o valor de propriedades que possuem esse formato.

Comment: Pode dar um contexto maior de como isto está sendo utilizado?

Comment: @bigown Eu estava fazendo um dojo que não podia alterar um script e tinha um array de Promises, queria uma forma de identificar as Promises antes delas serem resolvidas

Comment: @LFZiron a minha resposta resolveu o que perguntavas?

Comment: @Sergio perfeitamente, obrigado

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Esses `[[ ]]` são a maneira adotada para representar propriedades internas da promise visualmente. A [especificação da ECMAScript 6 diz assim](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-object-internal-methods-and-internal-slots):

> Internal methods and internal slots are identified within this specification using names enclosed in double square brackets [[ ]].

Ou seja:

> Métodos internos são identificados usando os seus nomes rodeados por colchetes (parenteses retos em PT_pt).

Esses métodos/propriedades são internos à *Promise* e só podem ser usados/revelados através de `.then()` ou `.catch()` que são respetivamente os métodos chamados em caso de sucesso e falha da *Promise*. Portanto esses `[[ ]]` não são variáveis com um valor mas sim métodos a ser chamados em caso de sucesso ou falha, e sendo chamado um deles o valor da *Promise* é revelado, por exclusão do outro não chamado.

Comment: Que bizarro, apesar de serem privados o console tem acesso ao nome e valor, mas o script não.

Comment: @LFZiron sim, correto. A consola tem acesso porque é uma ferramenta para desenvolvimento, mas o script não tem acesso porque é uma propriedade interna e não é exposta fora da _Promise_.

Comment: Existe alguma forma de nós criarmos uma propriedade assim em nossos objetos?

Comment: @LFZiron "propriedade assim" queres dizer uma propriedade interna que apareça dessa maneira na consola? Que eu saiba não.